# Data Summarizing of categorical medical variable

Tags: r, summary

This is my data subset

```
dput(head(AMC))
structure(list(`NCT Number` = c("NCT03987958", "NCT02809092", 
"NCT02860793", "NCT04069208", "NCT02319135", "NCT02920008"), 
    Status = c("Recruiting", "Active, not recruiting", "Completed", 
    "Recruiting", "Completed", "Completed"), `Study Results` = c("No Results Available", 
    "No Results Available", "No Results Available", "No Results Available", 
    "No Results Available", "No Results Available"), Conditions = c("Acute Myeloid Leukemia", 
    "Acute Myeloid Leukemia", "Acute Myeloid Leukemia", "Acute Myeloid Leukemia", 
    "Acute Myeloid Leukemia", "Acute Myeloid Leukemia"), Interventions = c(NA, 
    "Biological: NK Cells + Chemotherapy Starting", "Other: Bone marrow aspiration|Other: Blood sampling", 
    "Drug: Idarubicin and cytarabine induction", "Drug: Azacitadine|Drug: Fludarabine|Drug: Cytarabine|Drug: Lenograstim|Drug: Filgastrim", 
    "Drug: guadecitabine|Drug: Treatment Choice (TC)"), Gender = c("All", 
    "All", "All", "All", "All", "All"), Age = c("18 Years and older   (Adult, Older Adult)", 
    "2 Years to 59 Years   (Child, Adult)", "18 Years and older   (Adult, Older Adult)", 
    "18 Years to 60 Years   (Adult)", "65 Years and older   (Older Adult)", 
    "18 Years and older   (Adult, Older Adult)"), Phases = c(NA, 
    "Phase 1|Phase 2", "Not Applicable", "Phase 2", "Phase 3", 
    "Phase 3"), Enrollment = c(100, 30, 10, 42, 289, 302), `Study Type` = c("Observational", 
    "Interventional", "Interventional", "Interventional", "Interventional", 
    "Interventional"), `Study Designs` = c("Observational Model: Cohort|Time Perspective: Prospective", 
    "Allocation: N/A|Intervention Model: Single Group Assignment|Masking: None (Open Label)|Primary Purpose: Treatment", 
    "Allocation: N/A|Intervention Model: Single Group Assignment|Masking: None (Open Label)|Primary Purpose: Basic Science", 
    "Allocation: N/A|Intervention Model: Single Group Assignment|Masking: None (Open Label)|Primary Purpose: Treatment", 
    "Allocation: Randomized|Intervention Model: Parallel Assignment|Masking: None (Open Label)|Primary Purpose: Treatment", 
    "Allocation: Randomized|Intervention Model: Parallel Assignment|Masking: None (Open Label)|Primary Purpose: Treatment"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

############################################################################

```
head(AMC)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  `NCT Number` Status   `Study Results`  Conditions  Interventions       Gender Age      Phases Enrollment `Study Type` `Study Designs`       
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>            <chr>       <chr>               <chr>  <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                 
1 NCT03987958  Recruit… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… NA                  All    18 Year… NA            100 Observation… Observational Model: …
2 NCT02809092  Active,… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… Biological: NK Cel… All    2 Years… Phase…         30 Interventio… Allocation: N/A|Inter…
3 NCT02860793  Complet… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… Other: Bone marrow… All    18 Year… Not A…         10 Interventio… Allocation: N/A|Inter…
4 NCT04069208  Recruit… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… Drug: Idarubicin a… All    18 Year… Phase…         42 Interventio… Allocation: N/A|Inter…
5 NCT02319135  Complet… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… Drug: Azacitadine|… All    65 Year… Phase…        289 Interventio… Allocation: Randomize…
6 NCT02920008  Complet… No Results Avai… Acute Myel… Drug: guadecitabin… All    18 Year… Phase…        302 Interventio… Allocation: Randomize…
```

How do I summarize the data ,leaving the first column apart which is my reference to map.

If i take Status or gender or age etc together it is straight forward but in column which contains the Interventions consists of multiple words together. I would like to see that being summarized as well .

So leaving the first column my objective is to see the data summary.

How to do it , any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

**Expected output**

```
table(AMC$Status,AMC$`Study Results`, AMC$`Study Type`)
, ,  = Expanded Access

                         
                          Has Results No Results Available
  Active, not recruiting            0                    0
  Approved for marketing            0                    2
  Available                         0                    3
  Completed                         0                    0
  Enrolling by invitation           0                    0
  No longer available               0                    2
  Not yet recruiting                0                    0
  Recruiting                        0                    0
  Suspended                         0                    0
  Terminated                        0                    0
  Unknown status                    0                    0
  Withdrawn                         0                    0

, ,  = Expanded Access:Individual Patients

                         
                          Has Results No Results Available
  Active, not recruiting            0                    0
  Approved for marketing            0                    1
  Available                         0                    2
  Completed                         0                    0
  Enrolling by invitation           0                    0
  No longer available               0                    2
  Not yet recruiting                0                    0
  Recruiting                        0                    0
  Suspended                         0                    0
  Terminated                        0                    0
  Unknown status                    0                    0
  Withdrawn                         0                    0
```

The above is my expected output. But it seems it would be difficult to put all the variable except the first one in a table or one table as there are many levels i see. But it can be converted into something more concise ? Instead of making a table

Comment: How do you want to summarise the data? Can you show the expected output for the data shared?

Comment: okay ..will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with the too often forgotten function `ftable`.

```
ftable(AMC$Status,AMC$`Study Results`, AMC$`Study Type`)
#                                             Interventional Observational
#                                                                         
#Active, not recruiting No Results Available               1             0
#Completed              No Results Available               3             0
#Recruiting             No Results Available               1             1
```

Comment: i used table ...........................will use this..but i saw few where dplyr is being used summarie and turn then into proportion

Comment: @PesKchan In the question in post counts, not proportions.

Comment: yes .and .i did try to dplyr too, to  turn then into proportion to report it more concisely